# Rutas con angular

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un problema con una ruta creada. Verán lo que pasa es al hacer clic a un botón **ver más** con el cual paso un parámetro un **id**, el cual sirve para decirle a la ruta que tiene que buscar una publicación todo bien hasta ahí. El problema surge cuando la lista de elementos que muestro antes del boton ver mas es muy larga al hacer clic me cambia a la siguiente vista pero lo hace de forma que muestra la publicacion muy abajo y el contenido de esta esta en la parte de arriba.

Imagenes para tratar de explicar

[image: Pagina con scroll]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la segunda imagen se ve como conserva el scroll de la ruta anterior, cuando lo correcto seria que estuviera en la parte top de la pagina.

Hasta ahora lo unico que se me ocurre es que cuando llegue al controlador de la vista, hacer un

```
location.reload();
```

Pero el caso de utilizar angularjs es no tener que andar recargando las paginas.

Les agradecería si pudiesen ayudarme.